# Display HTML page inside mail body with editable email notification plugin in Jenkins

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Job in which I need to display the HTML file in the Automated Mail, The HTML filename is generated dynamically.

My query is that how to manage the dynamic html filename in Email extension plugin
I have tried using **${FILE,path="filename.html"} in the place of content in Jenkins. But the filename is getting changed automatically with the next builds

Is there any solution to overcome with freestyle or in pipeline script.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can try use the HTML code of the page as mail body. Then check it will be rendered as HTML page by mailbox.  I tried to generate HTML page by code and send HTML code by the Jenkins plugin, it worked.